# Counting emails using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First time posting - hopefully I am clear enough.

I'm not that expirienced with excel VBA, but have managed to find and change (with the help of my IT area) some code through these forums that counts the number of emails in outlook folders by a date in a cell. The code works fine when counting emails in one folder. What I need the code to do is count the emails in numerous folders (of which the list is stored in a sheet in the workbook) and output the count into seperate columns. (was hoping to post a picture as an example but I need a higher rep!)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub CountingEmails()
' Set Variables
Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim EmailCount As Integer, DateCount As Integer, iCount As Integer
Dim myDate As Date
Dim myCell As Object

Dim dictEmailDates As New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim folder1 As String, folder2 As String, folder3 As String
folder1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Cells(2, 5)
folder2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Cells(2, 6)
folder3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Cells(2, 7)

' Get Outlook Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' Get Folder Object
On Error Resume Next
Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders(folder1)

If Not IsEmpty(folder2) Then
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders(folder2)
End If
If Not IsEmpty(folder3) Then
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders(folder3)
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "Folder doesn't exist. Please ensure you have input the correct folder details."
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
FolderCount = objFolder.Folders.Count

' Put ReceivedTimes in array
CountEmails objFolder, dictEmailDates

' Clear Outlook objects
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

' Count the emails dates equal to active cell
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    DateCount = 0
    myDate = ActiveCell.Value

    If dictEmailDates.Exists(myDate) Then
        DateCount = dictEmailDates(myDate)
    End If

    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = DateCount
    Selection.Offset(1, -1).Activate
Loop
MsgBox "Count Complete", vbInformation, "Count of Emails."
End Sub

Sub CountEmails(objFolder, dictEmailDates)
EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
FolderCount = objFolder.Folders.Count

' Put ReceivedTimes in array
EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
For iCount = 1 To EmailCount
    With objFolder.Items(iCount)
        dateKey = DateSerial(Year(.ReceivedTime), Month(.ReceivedTime), Day(.ReceivedTime))
        If dictEmailDates.Exists(dateKey) Then
            dictEmailDates(dateKey) = dictEmailDates(dateKey) + 1
        Else
            dictEmailDates.Add dateKey, 1
        End If
    End With
Next iCount

For iCount = 1 To FolderCount
    CountEmails objFolder.Folders(iCount), dictEmailDates
Next iCount
End Sub
```

Hoping someone can help?? If there is anything extra or if I need to explain myself more please let me know!

Cheers, Adrian

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: I haven't been getting any error messages, it just counts the first folder and outputs the count into the column next to the date range. I want the code to be able to move to the next folder in the list and output the count into the next available column and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following, the issue is that `folder1` (or 2 or 3) is the only folder being counted. The issue looks to be that you only ever load one folder into your dictionary (based on the code I would think it was `folder3`). I would address that by restructuring the code as follows (I also added some performance improvements and removed a bunch of stuff that looked to be doing nothing):

```
Sub CountingEmails()
' Set Variables
Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim myDate As Date
Dim dictEmailDates As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Integer
Dim dcell As Range 'refering to range saves you having to keep retyping range to use,
'reducing likelihood of typo
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'refering to ws saves having to type out
'Sheet1 each time, and also makes it easier to update code if sheet name ever changes

'Turn off screen updates for faster run
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get the Outlook items setup
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Start looping through the folders
i = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Cells.Cells(2, 5 + i))
    ' Get Folder Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders(ws.Cells.Cells(2, 5 + i))

    'Get count of items and put in array based on ReceivedTimes
    CountEmails objFolder, dictEmailDates
Loop

'Notice I completely removed Date and Folder count from this sub, they were only ever
'set here, not used. Looked like legacy code from attempting to perform the count in
'this sub rather than the self-referencing sub you created.

' Clear Outlook objects
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

' Count the emails dates equal to current cell
i = 2
Set dcell = ws.Range("A" & i)
Do Until IsEmpty(dcell)

    DateCount = 0
    myDate = dcell.Value

    If dictEmailDates.Exists(myDate) Then
        DateCount = dictEmailDates(myDate)
    End If

    dcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = DateCount
    i = i + 1
    Set dcell = ws.Range("A" & i)
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Count Complete", vbInformation, "Count of Emails."
End Sub

Sub CountEmails(objFolder, dictEmailDates)
EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
FolderCount = objFolder.Folders.Count

' Put ReceivedTimes in array
For iCount = 1 To EmailCount
    With objFolder.Items(iCount)
        dateKey = DateSerial(Year(.ReceivedTime), Month(.ReceivedTime), Day(.ReceivedTime))
        If dictEmailDates.Exists(dateKey) Then
            dictEmailDates(dateKey) = dictEmailDates(dateKey) + 1
        Else
            dictEmailDates.Add dateKey, 1
        End If
    End With
Next iCount

For iCount = 1 To FolderCount
    CountEmails objFolder.Folders(iCount), dictEmailDates
Next iCount
End Sub
```